# Usage of 'barring' to mean 'except'

Tags: verbs, subjects, objects

While trying to find example sentences online for another question on this site, I realized I didn't fully understand the usage of 'barring' to mean 'except'. Here is an example:

> *I was basically the only David I knew, barring my Uncle Dave of course.* [source](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/sentences-with-the-word/barring.html)

To be clear, I understand what the sentence means. My question is, **Who or what is doing the barring?**

Uncle Dave is obviously the one who gets barred from the statement, but is it the speaker who is barring him? Is it simply a way of illustrating that the statement is only true on the condition that Uncle Dave is excluded as a person named David, and nothing is doing the barring? I'm thoroughly confused and probably overthinking it, but any help would be appreciated!

*P.S. I apologize for my lack of scholarly vocabulary, but I didn't want to use any incorrect terms or confuse anybody.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the speaker who is "barring", to establish the meaning of their statement, just as the speaker would be doing the "excepting" if "except" had been used. It's a headword in this dictionary:

[Merriam-Webster "barring"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barring)
excluding by exception : excepting *… they knew that, barring a miracle, they would never be able to save the large cash outlay required …*